# Find coordinates relative to base C and canonical basis of trilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, change-of-basis

Let $C=\{(3,1),(2,1)\}$ be basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.How to find coordinates for trilinear form $H=e^1\bigotimes e^1\bigotimes e^2 - e^2\bigotimes e^2\bigotimes e^1$ relative to $C$ and canonical basis.

$e^1,e^2,e^3$ are elements of a dual canonical basis.

Comment: What is your definition of the "canonical basis" here? It seems as though $H$ is already represented relative to what I would call the "canonical basis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new basis is written
$$b_1=3e_1+e_2,$$
$$b_2=2e_1+e_2.$$

Solving for $e_1,e_2$ 
$$e_1=b_1-b_2,$$
$$e_2=-b_1+3b_2.$$

Since one wants $e^i(e_j)=\delta^i_j$, the duals for $b_i$ are
$$b^1=e^1-2e^2,$$
$$b^1=-e^1+3e^2.$$
Then one can check that $b^i(b_j)=\delta^i_j$.
Solving for $e^1,e^2$ will give
$$e^1=3b^1+2b^2,$$
$$e^2=b^1+b^2.$$

Subbing on the terms of $H$ gives
$$e^1\otimes e^1\otimes e^2=(3b^1+2b^2)\otimes(3b^1+2b^2)\otimes(b^1+b^2),$$
and
$$e^2\otimes e^2\otimes e^1=(b^1+b^2)\otimes(b^1+b^2)\otimes(3b^1+2b^2),$$
that can be simplified by the use of distributive properties, then to assemble your $H$.

Can you take it from here?

**Addendum**:

Let me illustrate more with $e^1\otimes e^1\otimes e^2$.
This is 
$$=e^1\otimes(3b^1\otimes b^1+3b^1\otimes b^2+2b^2\otimes b^1+2b^2\otimes b^2),$$

$$=(3b^1+2b^2)\otimes(3b^1\otimes b^1+3b^1\otimes b^2+2b^2\otimes b^1+2b^2\otimes b^2),$$

$$=9b^1\otimes b^1\otimes b^1+
9b^1\otimes b^1\otimes b^2+
6b^1\otimes b^2\otimes b^1+
6b^1\otimes b^2\otimes b^2+
6b^2\otimes b^1\otimes b^1+\\
6b^2\otimes b^1\otimes b^2+
4b^2\otimes b^2\otimes b^1+
4b^2\otimes b^2\otimes b^2.$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand everything you posted (Assuming there are few slips of a pen) but I am not sure how to continue from this point.

Comment: Ok, I detected one, but if you see more tell please. With a simpler example, here I illustrated what's next: $$e^1\otimes e^2=(3b^1+2b^2)\otimes(b^1+b^2),$$ $$=3b^1\otimes b^1+3b^1\otimes b^2+2b^2\otimes b^1+2b^2\otimes b^2,$$ distributing

Comment: Fourth equation row, I think you've used e instead of b. I just don't know that to do with these tensor products. Actually that's the most difficult part for me.

Comment: done. I'm going to add in my answer.

Comment: One last question. Does $e_1\bigotimes e_2=e_2\bigotimes e_1$?

Comment: No, $e^1\otimes e^1$, $e^1\otimes e^2$, $e^2\otimes e^1$ and $e^2\otimes e^2$ are four different basics tensors for the 4 dimensional vector space dubbed **rank two tensors** over $\mathbb R^2$, for rank three there are eight basics $e^i\otimes e^j\otimes e^k$ : )